# Serverless: dynamodb delete where condition

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am trying, and failing, to delete a record with a condition. I keep getting this error: `The provided key element does not match the schema`.

This is my definition in the yml:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    vuelosTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Delete
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          -
            AttributeName: vuelta
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          -
            AttributeName: vuelta
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

These are the params when trying to delete:

```
params = {
    RequestItems: {
      [process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE]: [{
        DeleteRequest: {
          Key: {
            "vuelta": "2017-09-09"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  };
```

I know it's something I am not getting, but I don't know what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your table key is both `id` and `vuelta` but you're only providing `vuelta` in the delete request. Modify the key in your delete request so it contains both the `id` and `vuelta`.

Also, depending on your client library may need to specify

```
Key: {
  id: { S: "some value" },
  vuelta: { S: "some value" }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but that limits me. I have to have the ID in order to delete. I want to be able to delete having only the vuelta value. Also, consider that vuelta is not unique among different records.

Comment: DeleteItem only removes a single item. There isn't a bulk remove API. Your only option is to scan/query the table or it's indexes to find the keys then remove them individually.

Comment: I am using batchWrite, which can be used to put/delete docs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Comment: You still need to specify the hash and range as the key for each item to be removed. What you're looking for (a combined query + delete API) doesn't currently exist.